# Debezium Oracle Connector - jmx metrics attribute type string not populating to Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, grafana, apache-kafka-connect, jmx, debezium

We configured successfully the Oracle Debezium connector and are receiving messages for any related database changes. We also activated the jmx exporter to get the metrics into prometheus using kafka-connect to build Grafana Dashboard.

The issue we are facing is, that the metrics for the additional streaming  MBean are not showing any values at Prometheus but when looking at them in jconsole it's there. Also noticed that those metrics having **type** `string` is not showing rest all are showing. (please refer screen shots)

[image: Debezium]

**Attributes** are having Type `String` is not showing
[image: Type 'String' is not showing]

All other metrics scraping and listing over Prometheus.
[image: All other metrics scraping]

We have whitelisted all Debezium metrics

```
whitelistObjectNames:
  # BEGIN This to whitelist Debezium for scrape Metrics
  - debezium.*:type=*connector-metrics,*
  # END This to whitelist Debezium for scrape Metrics
  # Engine Application Versioning Info
```

Rules are in place to scrape metrics

```
rules:
  # BEGIN This is pattern to scrape Debezium Metrics
  - pattern: "debezium.([^:]+)<type=connector-metrics, context=([^,]+), server=([^>]+)>([^:]+)"
    name: "debezium_metrics_$4"
    labels:
       plugin: "$1"
       name: "$3"
       context: "$2"
  # END This is pattern to scrape Debezium Metrics
```

Prometheus is showing metrics as below.

[image: Prometheus metrics]

We are able to see them in connect cluster logs (connect.log)

Streaming metrics dump: OracleStreamingChangeEventSourceMetrics{**currentScn**=1564244611647, oldestScn=1564244608872, **committedScn**=1564244611634, **offsetScn**=1564244608871, logMinerQueryCount=15163, totalProcessedRows=1057165, totalCapturedDmlCount=384093, totalDurationOfFetchingQuery=PT8H17M57.956106S, lastCapturedDmlCount=0, lastDurationOfFetchingQuery=PT6.278791S, maxCapturedDmlCount=56322, maxDurationOfFetchingQuery=PT43.061947S, totalBatchProcessingDuration=PT8H35M26.018633S, lastBatchProcessingDuration=PT6.388703S, maxBatchProcessingThroughput=8694, currentLogFileName=

We want all Scn (i.e. CurrentScn, committedScn, offsetScn, etc) at Prometheus although we are able to find `ScnFreezeCount` but the type of this attribute is `int`.

please find link of metrics which can be scrapped from Debezium

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/oracle.html#oracle-streaming-metrics-currentscn

If anyone could help us out, this would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this question on [Debezium Google Group](https://groups.google.com/g/debezium/c/aUO9X5uGRF0) as well and you can see answer there. To quote it here:

> Most of those you showed are related to either String-based or String Array-based types, and AFAIK these are not supported in Prometheus.  The driving factor for expressing these as String values is because in high volume or older Oracle databases, the SCN values have likely extended beyond Long.MAX_VALUE and therefore cannot be represented by a simple Long.